# Access Denied upon order completion

Tags: 7, commerce

in drupal commerce every time logged in as a authenticated user and can get all the way through checkout until I am redirected back to the site.

redirected to this page:

/checkout/15/payment/return/GSudAHSfaC6km6N5qbLb8jNB8Wu3x3DZ0TzvWT0O4io?payment_method=paypal&token=EC-5Y966101448403611&PayerID=HF6BGTV3LGDT4

I get sometimes an Access Denied error and logout ! and The order is not processed. And sometimes is ok and processed complete !

I can't see that I am missing any permissions that would prevent anything. I also can't see where I would specify the page to return the user to at this point in the process. Any thoughts?

This problem only on chrome ! firefox is ok !!

Comment: `I'm testing out this module now in conjunction with the Paypal Express Checkout module.`-- Which other module?

Comment: i edit my qs Bro

Comment: SAME PROBLEM !!!!

Comment: Firefox is ok but with chrome user disconnected after redirect to site !

Comment: @PatrickKenny Any help ?